# AS3 error 1119: Access of undefined property CHANGE through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This might be a bug in AS3 because the event its listing in the error is not associated with a mouseEvent, but I'd really like to get to the bottom of this. I've been working on this project and have a movieclip for a search feature with 3 combos and 2 input text fields inside. When user enters text into text field I want to disable the combos, set the selected index to -1. If user clears the text fields I want the combos enabled. CS4 is throwing the above error. It's so weird or is it me?

My code:

```
fltr.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shwSrch);
function shwSrch(Event:MouseEvent):void{
        popcmb1(); //function to populate combo 1
        srch.canNow.button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cans);
        srch.srchNow.button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gos);
        srch.npt1.it.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtchng);
        srch.npt1.it.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }
function txtchng(event:Event):void{
        if  (srch.npt1.it.length >0){
            //DISABLE COMBO AND NPT2
            srch.cmb1.cmb.enabled           = false;
            srch.cmb1.cmb.selectedIndex     = -1;
            srch.cmb1.cmb.prompt            = "All";
            cmb1si                          = gSrch.cmb1.cmb.selectedIndex;
            }
        else{
            srch.cmb1.cmb.enabled           = true;
            srch.npt1.it.selectable         = true;
            srch.npt1.it.type               = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            srch.npt1.it.borderColor        = 0x000000;
            }
        npt1 = srch.npt1.text;
        }
```

So, When I run this newly added code it throws  error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.
I have already  the line 'import flash.events.Event;'
I've experimented quite a bit and noted that if I create a separate function for listeners and then call it from with the shwSrch function thus:

```
function lstnrs():void{
        srch.npt1.it.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtchng);
        srch.npt1.it.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }
```

It works... Is there anyone that can shine some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are naming your variables.

```
function shwSrch(Event:MouseEvent):void
```

Here you use `Event` as the parameter name which is a bad choice, because it's the same name the `Event` class has. Later, you add a listener.

```
srch.npt1.it.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtchng);
```

Now it's unclear if you are referring to the class or the parameter variable name. For the latter,  you receive the error.

To solve the problem, use the convention to start variable names with a lower case letter and class names with capital ones.

```
function shwSrch(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
```

Side note: do you really need to display the event after adding the listener for it like here for example?

```
    srch.npt1.it.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtchng);
    srch.npt1.it.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
```

If you do not use the parameter in the handler function, you could simply do

```
    srch.npt1.it.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtchng);
    txtchng(null);
```

Comment: What you've suggested does make sense and I'd never really given it much thought until now. I've tried your suggestion and it works quite nicely.... Still on an AS3 learning curve but tthanks for your advise.